# Problem with juju hadoop deploy

Tags: juju, hadoop

I've run into a problem deploying the juju hadoop charm.

juju bootstrap works fine, but when I use `juju deploy hadoop hadoop-master`, I get an install error.

juju status gives me:

```
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: local
    instance-state: running
services:
    hadoop-master:
    charm: cs:precise/hadoop-5
    relations: {}
    units:
    hadoop-master/0:
    agent-state: install-error
    machine: 0
    public-address: xx.x.x.xxx
```

Here is my juju debug-log:

```
2013-01-29 07:35:44,689 unit:hadoop-master/0: hook.output INFO: ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

2013-01-29 07:35:45,208 unit:hadoop-master/0: hook.output INFO: Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc

2013-01-29 07:35:45,220 unit:hadoop-master/0: hook.output INFO: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

2013-01-29 07:35:45,223 unit:hadoop-master/0: hook.output DEBUG: hook install exited, exit code Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: juju.errors.CharmInvocationError: Error processing '/var/lib/juju/units/hadoop-master-0/charm/hooks/install': exit code 100.
.
2013-01-29 07:35:45,223 unit:hadoop-master/0: hook.executor DEBUG: Hook error: /var/lib/juju/units/hadoop-master-0/charm/hooks/install Error processing '/var/lib/juju/units/hadoop-master-0/charm/hooks/install': exit code 100.
2013-01-29 07:35:45,224 unit:hadoop-master/0: statemachine DEBUG: unitworkflowstate:  executing error transition error_install, Error processing '/var/lib/juju/units/hadoop-master-0/charm/hooks/install': exit code 100.
2013-01-29 07:35:45,582 unit:hadoop-master/0: statemachine DEBUG: unitworkflowstate: transition error_install (None -> install_error) {}
2013-01-29 07:35:45,630 unit:hadoop-master/0: statemachine DEBUG: unitworkflowstate: transition complete error_install (state install_error) {}
2013-01-29 07:35:45,659 unit:hadoop-master/0: juju.agents.unit DEBUG: Configuration Changed
2013-01-29 07:35:45,659 unit:hadoop-master/0: juju.agents.unit DEBUG: Configuration updated on service in a non-started state
2013-01-29 07:35:45,730 unit:hadoop-master/0: juju.agents.unit INFO: No upgrade flag set.
```

What's the fix?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! On this Q&A site we post answers (solutions) as answers. I'll post your answer as a CW-post now. It's alright to answer your own questions here, but being a new user this isn't possible straightaway probably.

Answer (score 4):

As posted by [user127018](https://askubuntu.com/users/127018/user127018) (OP) in his question:

> Solution: I am answering my question. I could fix the problem by
>   adding a line in the `~/.juju/environments.yaml`:
>
> ```
> juju-origin: proposed
> ```
>
> The fix was posted [in LP Bug #1060404](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1060404).